# Can I add a poster to the audio player?

Tags: image, background, mediaelement.js, poster

I'd like to add a poster to my audio player previews just like with the video mode of the mediaelement.js player.

I've checked all the shortcodes and there doesn't seem to be anything for this. Basically all I want is a static image immediately above the audio player that is visible before and during playing.

The reason I want this to be an 'all-in-one' player is because my WP theme allows me to create posts in the 'audio' format so that the audio player appears at the top of my category view of recent posts. It'd be awesome to add that image for each post and have it part of the audio player. Kind of like video but with less overhead.

Thanks in advance.